# Android - Retrofit does not display data

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to learn Retrofit making simple weather app and I have some problem. I made two methods to display data in Activity and method does not work outside onCreate, but second one in works. In Android Profiler I can see JSON logs, but still I don't see anything in Activity. What's the problem?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(WeatherAPI_Interface.API_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    WeatherAPI_Interface weatherAPIInterface = retrofit.create(WeatherAPI_Interface.class);

    latitude = 37.8267;
    longitude = -122.4233;
    Call<Currently> call = weatherAPIInterface.getWeather(latitude, longitude);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Currently>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Currently> call, @NonNull Response<Currently> response) {
            temp_textview.setText(String.valueOf(response.body().getCurrently().getTemperature()));
            city_textview.setText(response.body().getTimezone());
            image_View.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(response.body().getCurrently().getIcon()));

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Currently> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

        }
    });

}


@Override
public  void getCurrentWeather(final Currently currently) {
    latitude = 37.8267;
    longitude = -122.4233;
    NetworkClient.getInstance().getWeather(latitude, longitude).enqueue(new Callback<Currently>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Currently> call, @NonNull Response<Currently> response) {

            weather_textview.setText((CharSequence) response.body().getCurrently().getSummary());
            pressure_textview.setText((CharSequence) response.body().getDaily().getData());
            temp_textview.setText(String.valueOf(currently.getCurrently().getTemperature()));

            Log.d(TAG, "City" + currently.getLatitude());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Currently> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed" + t.getMessage());
        }
    });



}



 public class NetworkClient {

private static WeatherAPI_Interface service;

public static WeatherAPI_Interface getInstance() {
    if (service == null) {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(WeatherAPI_Interface.API_URL)
                .build();
        service = retrofit.create(WeatherAPI_Interface.class);
        return service;

    }
    else {
        return service;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't call the function how can it work?

when the activity starts it'll run the code in OnCreate ( and any call in it) only, so to run any function outside it you need to call it.